# My migration isn't creating uuid column for my foreign key, I have also tried foreignUuid function but still getting error

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have attached my semester migration code and semester seeder code. Kindly tell me if you need any other pictures for guidance.

when I send data through seeders It only takes the numbers but not the string, because it creates an integer column in the database, Help me someone who knows about laravel migrations.

At the end, you can also see the database table of seemster.

[[image: Semester Migration file][1]]

[image: Semester Seeder]

[image: Semester table in database]

Comment: Please show us what is getting generated exactly. Is `id` of `degrees` table also uuid?

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: yes id of degree table is also UUID, I have also done the same code in different project its only giving me error in this one.

Comment: @Muhammad Talha please display here model details for more reference to solve the question

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignIdFor):

*The foreignIdFor method adds a {column}_id UNSIGNED BIGINT equivalent column for a given model class*

Which basically means, it is creating `BIGINT` column in database not `char` like uuid.

It is better to use:

```
$table->foreignUuid('degreeId');
```

in migration.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Support\Str::orderUuid does not exist.
i'm getting this error when I run seed command

Comment: @MuhammadTalha Check edited answer

Comment: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "degreeId" of relation "semesters" does not exist

its giving that error after I have included your code

Comment: did you `migrate:refresh` the table? Check your table to see if it still has degreeId column

Comment: column "uuid" of relation "semesters" does not exist

after running migrate:refresh command now its giving me that error

Comment: Now in seeder file my $DCS1 variable is not getting the uuid value

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest revisiting your approach of using UUID. I believe you have missed some steps on your way while implementing UUID.

Add this to Semester Model

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Create a trait

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
trait Uuids
{

    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

Use this trait in the semester Model

Follow this brilliant article from medium and if the problem persists post it here again to ask your questions

https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088